# How do I call for multiple reuse identifiers if I manually added cells in storyboard for collectionViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am practicing some coding on collectionViews. However I like to work in Main.storyboard to see what I am working with visually. Unfortunately it appears that makes more work on my end when working in the viewController because this would have been much faster  if done  programmatically.

I am trying to call for multiple reuse identifiers for the collectionViewCell. However I only know how to call one cell. Now I am not getting any errors, I just do not know how to display all of the cells when I run the program.

**Here is the code.**

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Fashion Cell 0", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

When I **run** the app I get this.

[image]

Please note, in Main.Storyboard I am add the cells manually. 
**Example**:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do in this way

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Fashion Cell 0", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } 

     if indexPath.item == 1 {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Fashion Cell 1”, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } 
    //…… 


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Fashion Cell 0", for: indexPath)
    return cell
    }
```

Although you can use **switch** instead of **if** for better readability

Comment: I'm getting this error "Missing return in a function expected to return 'UICollectionViewCell'"  trying to figure it out to see if it works when I run it. I entered your code the exact way.

Comment: App is now crashing with error       "the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'"

Comment: yes because you have to handle all case. will updated answer.  ideally return UICollectionViewCell() never execute you are missing the case for e.g there are 6 cell all cases from 0..5 should be handled.

Comment: @Clint atLeast reply to someOne helps. It make the community strengthen.

Comment: Oh I thought I had already replied to you sorry. I just went ahead and did it programmatically. - thanks

Comment: Welcome, if you think this answer is correct please accept this answer no issue otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can not in this way.Create one array of your number of images and set it to collectionView. No need to more cell in storyboard.

```
 let video:[UIImage] = ["","","",""]


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return video.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! yourcellfile


    let image = video[indexPath.row]
    cell.img.image = image

    return cell

}
```

You can go this way. It's proper method to imaplement collectionview.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding you mate. Are you saying there is no need for me to have more than one cell in a storyboard?

Comment: You create one array of your all images and like above your can set it in cell imageview in collectionview. no need to more cell in collectionview only one cell and imageview inside it

Comment: Certainly if the only difference between the cells is the image then there is no need for multiple cell types.

Comment: Oh I understand, I just wanted to visually see all of the cells in the storyboard. Even if it means having to put 20 cells.